# How to override a function signature from a external library in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, overriding

Is is it possible to override a function signature of a external package with your own types?

Let's say I have a external package called `translationpackage` and I want to use the `translate` function of it.

The package defines the function as follows:

```
// original signature
function translate(key: string) : string;
```

Now I want to override it to only accept the keys `'foo' | 'bar'`. Which would be written like the following example if I would implement the `translate` function my self.

```
// my own signature
function translate(key: 'foo' | 'bar'): string
```

What do I have to do in order to get Typescript to use my own signature instead of the original one everywhere I import `translate`?

```
import { translate } from 'translationpackage'
```

**Edit:** I know that `d.ts` files can be used if the imported module has no own type definitions. However it seems that this does not work when I try to override existing types.

The following code is almost what I'm looking for but typescript ignores it in favor of the types that come with the package.

```
declare module 'translationpackage' {
  export function translate(key: 'foo' | 'bar'): string;
}
```

Comment: But that's exactly how you do it.. `function translate(key: 'foo' | 'bar'): string` is the solution. What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

You will have do implement a `translate` wrapper for yourself that wraps the function from `translatepackage`.

```
// my-translate.ts
import { translate } from 'translationpackage'

export const myTranslate = (key: 'foo' | 'bar'): string => translate(key)

// my-other-file.ts
import { myTranslate } from 'my-translate'

console.log(myTranslate('foo'))
```